# Ugin's Condition Tokens & Doubling effects

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Using [Ugin, the ineffable](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUgin%2c%20the%20ineffable%5d)'s +1 ability that creates a token with the condition that if it leaves play, return the related exiled card to hand.
How does this condition interact with effects such as [Doubling Season](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoubling%20Season%5d)'s (or similar cards) x2 token production.

If either token leaves play do you return the exiled card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is addressed by one of the Gatherer rulings for Ugin:

> If an effect such as that of Doubling Season causes Ugin to create two Spirit tokens, you still only exile one card from your library. You’ll put that card into your hand the first time that either of the tokens leaves the battlefield.

Comment: The ability also triggers the when the other token leaves the battlefield. It simply does nothing because it the exiled card no longer exists. This would be relevant if the first ability is countered, for example.

Comment: Where are the comp rules for that? Is this a case of an ability being linked to itself; as described in 607.1c?

Comment: I think there is a linked ability here, but I don't think that addresses the main issue. The main thing is that making two tokens effectively changes the triggered ability to "Whenever either of those tokens leaves the battlefield...". I'm not sure what a good rule reference is for that.